# Spring boot application issues with using springdoc-openapi-javadoc

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, openapi, javadoc, lombok

I am using `springdoc-openapi-ui` (Version `1.6.12`) in my spring boot application (Spring boot version `2.7.2`) for API documentation. It works fine and I had no issue with it. However I wanted to add the feature to push `javadoc` comments to `swagger-ui` as well.

For that I did add the dependency `springdoc-openapi-javadoc` (Version `1.6.12`) to my POM file. To support the dependency to push the `javadoc` comments, I did add the following maven plugin as well which is required by the documentations.

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <annotationProcessorPaths>
                <path>
                    <groupId>com.github.therapi</groupId>
                    <artifactId>therapi-runtime-javadoc-scribe</artifactId>
                    <version>0.15.0</version>
                </path>
            </annotationProcessorPaths>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

After adding the plugin and the dependency, I had so many issues within the application. As an example, I could not add new logs and build the application. I am adding logs using `lombok` and its annotation `@Slf4j`. The moment I add a new log, I get the following error.

```
java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable log
  location: class com.example.swaggerDemo.controllers.BookController
```

The root cause for this issue is not very clear for me. Did anyone faced the same issue? Is there a solution available or is there something wrong in my implementation which is leading to this error?

Your advices are kindly appreciated and thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `lombok` and `therapi-runtime-javadoc-scribe` to the `maven-compiler-plugin` configuration

ie.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <annotationProcessorPaths>
            <path>
                <groupId>com.github.therapi</groupId>
                <artifactId>therapi-runtime-javadoc-scribe</artifactId>
                <version>0.15.0</version>
            </path>
            <path>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                <version>${lombok.version}</version>
            </path>
        </annotationProcessorPaths>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```